# Extracting elements plotted on Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I have the website about the planet occultations by Moon.

https://eco.mtk.nao.ac.jp/cgi-bin/koyomi/occulx_p_en.cgi

There are "Occultation maps", which are very nice:
[image]

I tried to use the [Web Scraper for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper-free-web-scra/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en), but it looks like it grabs the stuff to Excel only.

I would like to extract this occultation map to a KML file or similar. Is it possible?

Comment: In short, you need the red lines as a spatial file, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. Only the red lines. Next, they could be filled up in QGIS.

Comment: Hello @MKR I have proposed an answer if anything is not clear don't hesitate to tag me, I could then adapt my answer.

Comment: Hi Sir.
I know, let me give it a go tomorrow. I was busy today. It looks like we will be on the right track. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lines data displayed in the map is in a .js file named `gmaps202101.js`.
You can get a GeoJSON text of all polylines coded in the file.

- Open  `Dev Tools Ctrl+Shift+C > Sources Tab > Page Tab`.
- Navigate to `eco.mtk.nao.ac.jp > koyomi > koyomix/poclgmap/koyomix > gmaps202101.js` file.
- Copy all content of the file.
- Go to `Snippets tab > New snippet`. Paste the code.
- Add the following lines to `set_Map` function (right above `return`)

  ```js
  lines = [line0, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6];    
  exportGeoJson(lines);
  ```
- Add the following lines to the end of the file and run (<kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd>). This prints to the console a JSON object.

  ```js
  function exportGeoJson(lines) {
      var geoJson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": []
      };

      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

          var lineFeature = {
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "LineString",
                  "coordinates": []
              },
              "properties": {}
          };

          path = lines[i].getPath();
          for (var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++) {
              var pt = path.getAt(j);
              lineFeature.geometry.coordinates.push([
                  pt.lng(), pt.lat()
              ]);
          }

          geoJson.features.push(lineFeature);
      }

      console.log(geoJson);
  }

  set_Map();
  ```
- Copy/paste it into a text file. Save as `.geojson`.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: A better solution would be writing a PyQGIS script like J.Monticolo's answer to [your previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345786/fetching-the-on-click-data-from-the-website-into-qgis/).

Comment: My console is empty, here is the problem, there is no script snippet visible as you shown me in the demo version

Comment: @MKR What do you mean by "no script snippet visible"? You should copy all `gmaps202101.js`'s content to a "New snippet", then copy/paste the scripts above to the "New snippet". [Help for snippet](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets)

Comment: Yes I did exactly as you shown me. 
https://imgur.com/a/4f49kS1. I have nothing to click in the console.

Comment: @MKR Are you sure you added the last line -> `set_Map();`

Comment: Yes it is as the last line

Comment: @MKR Could you add a screenshot of the whole snippet content you run here?

Comment: Added:

https://imgur.com/a/4f49kS1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124243/discussion-between-kadir-sahbaz-and-mkr).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for your question (but may be the best is ask for the data to the producer).

First I searched for the data that is shown in red on the map. If you use chrome you can access dev tools then in the source tab you will find all the files used in the website.  Go to folder `eco.mtk.nao.ac.jp` then folder `koyomi` then `koyomixpoclgmap/koyomix` then the js file (the file name depend on the value you have used as parameter).

[image]

This file is the javascript command used to produce the map. In the function called set_Map there is variable named `points0` that contains the points to produce one of the line in red. Points location are stored as encoded format ([see documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)). The variable `line0` is used to create a google maps polyline to be traced on the map. This process is repeated for every line in the map (`points1` `line1` `points2` `line2`...).

The next step is to extract from the JS file the encoded value. You can use notepad find and replace to delete the part of the file you don't need and keep only the encoded values.

Then you have to decode the value to produce a GIS file. You can choose different solution to do it, the choice will depend on the process you are familiar with. Here are two different options you can use  :

1. Post Gis function to create line from encoded polyline. To use it you need to have access to a postgis database or to install postgis database in your computer. Use the encoded values to build a sql querry, [here is the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline.html).
2. javascript library made by mapbox to transform encoded value to geojson file. It could work in the console or in the browser [here is the documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/polyline)

After this step you get your geodata and you can use it in QGIS.

Comment: Hi,

Your answer is nice but, seems to be too difficult to me. First of all:
1. How to decode the coordinates in Javascript?
2. How to create the line in PostGIS? I am a newbie so far
3. Same to JavaScript Mapbox.