# Extracting elements plotted on OpenStreetMap canvas

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, geojson

I found a very nice website with eclipse maps, which example can be found here:

http://ytliu.epizy.com/eclipse/solar_eclipse_interactiveMap.html?ybeg=2001&ind=55&dT=69.49500924568443&k2=default&DE=431

Unfortunately after applying the function from this query:

[Extracting elements plotted on Google Maps API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395855/extracting-elements-plotted-on-google-maps-api)

I wasn't able to export these interactive lines to GeoJSON

[image]

How could I:

- download the existing map to the .geojson format

Comment: The Besselian math equation generates a js file. http://ytliu.epizy.com/eclipse/Besselian_solar_DE431/Bess2001.js where the coordinates to generate the line are. This is not GeoJSON.

Comment: So what is the other format in which it could be done?